# Blank CiviCRM Dashboard and Admin Pages On Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, developer

From a Fresh install of CiviCRM on drupal 7 I logged out of the system and logged In again into drupal, on Accessing the CiviCRM module on drupal it leads me to a blank page http://localhost/drupal/?q=civicrm/dashboard and also  http://localhost/drupal/?q=civicrm/admin.

Comment: Immediately i configured an extensions Directory and created a new extension i am to work on

Answer (score 1):

did you check if all permissions are OK and there is a civicrm_settings.php on /sites/default? Is there any message in the Drupal log (reports/recent log messages)?

Answer (score 1):

When experiencing a WSOD you can usually find a clue as to what may have happened in the PHP log file.

Where that file lives depends on your setup:
/var/log/httpd/error_log or eg
/var/log/apache2 or eg
/Applications/MAMP/logs